# Is there a better way to judge if one ruby hash within another?

Tags: ruby, hash

such as hash `a` is `{:name=>'mike',:age=>27,:gender=>'male'}`
and hash `b` is `{:name=>'mike'}`

I am wondering is there a better way to judge if `b` hash is within `a` hash instead of compare every keys one by one?

I 've found a way to do this, is this more effecient than compare keys?

a.merge(b)==a

Comment: Given it is a hash, comparing keys is **very efficient**, you don't have to care about it.

Comment: Also, the merge is inefficient as it is going to generate a **new** hash in memory, you should compare keys.

Comment: thanks Mauricio, guru you are!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the approach of calculating the intersection, which is what you're trying to do:

```
a = { :a => :b, :c => :d }
b = { :e => :f, :a => :b }
c = { :a => :f, :e => :c }

(a.to_a & b.to_a).any? # => true
(a.to_a & c.to_a).any? # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b.all? do |key, value|
  a.include? key &&
  a[key] == value   
end
```

This loop is linear in the size of b, because both steps  inside the loop take (on average) constant time.

Comment: Calling **include?** and then **a[key]** makes this code **very** inefficient, as it tries to find the key twice.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares: access to hashes is O(1) so I don't see why this would be inefficient. In fact I think this is the most conceptually efficient code (although converting to arrays and intersecting them may be faster because this intersection is implemented in C). I'd change `include?` to `has_key?`, it's a bit more clear. And why create a new (unindented) line for the second condition?